# Detecting Group Owner(GO) after wifi direct connection is made in UWP application

Tags: uwp, wifi-direct

I am making a simple test with wifi direct : connecting a PC and android phone and send/receive some data.

On the android side, it's clear who is the GO, but on the UWP application side, I searched the documentation and didn't find any function/property of the kind "isGroupOwner".

Does someone know how to get this information afther bot devices are connected?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you test the official sample about [WiFiDirect](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WiFiDirect)? It seems we should be able to set [`WiFiDirectAdvertisement.IsAutonomousGroupOwnerEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifidirect.wifidirectadvertisement.isautonomousgroupownerenabled).

Comment: My question was not precise enough : I was asking if there is a way to know GO status after negociation. Example, if both device have GO intent of 7, it may be useful to know which one is the GO immediately after negociation.

Comment: @Raph9023 How do you solve this issue finally? I have hit the same issue.